# Creating Internal C# classes from XSD.exe

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

I'm writing a library that will accept an XML string as input which it will deserialize and do some transformations on. The output will be a separate XML file with a different schema.

This internal XML will be following an internal Schema, which I do not wish to expose to the user of the library. The schema is defined in an XSD file in my project which I use XSD.exe (the one that comes bundled with Visual Studio) to create C# classes from.

The problem I have is that XSD.exe generates `public` classes. I would want them to be implicit or explicit `internal`.

Is there anyway I can make XSD.exe create `internal` classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it won't create `internal` classes.  Classes output by XSD.EXE are intended to be serialized by the `XMLSerializer`.  The `XMLSerializer` only supports public classes and thus if XSD output `internal` classes, serialization would fail.